# Sampling theorems for partition polynomials (associahedra, noncrossing partitions / parking functions)

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, convex-polytopes

Define the associahedra partition polynomial
$$
\begin{split}
A(x) &= 1 + A_1(u_1) z + A_2(u_1,u_2) z^2 + A_3(u_1,u_2,u_3) z^3 + \cdots\\
& \qquad\qquad = 1 + \sum_{n \geq 1} A_n(u_1,...,u_n) z^n
\end{split}
$$
with
$$
\begin{split}
A_n(u_1,...,u_n) &= \sum_\text{partitions of $n$} M(e_1,e_2,...,e_n) u_1^{e_1}u_2^{e_3}\ldots u_n^{e_n}\\
&= \sum_\text{partitions of $n$} (-1)^{Se} \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{(n+Se)!}{n!e_1!e_2!\ldots e_n!}    u_1^{e_1}u_2^{e_3}\ldots u_n^{e_n}
\end{split}
$$
for which the sum of the exponents $e_n$ is $Se = e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_n$ and a partition of $n$ satisfies $n = 1 \cdot e_1 + 2 \cdot e_2 + \cdots + n \cdot e_n$ where $n$ and $e_n$ are natural numbers, $(0,1,2,...)$, $z$ is a complex or real variable, and $(u_1,u_2,...)$ is an infinite set of mutually commutative indeterminates that commute with $z$ as well.

In analysis, $z \; A(z)$ is the formal compositional inverse of the formal power series / o.g.f. $O(z) = z(1+ \sum_{n \geq 1} u_1 z^n)$. In geometry / topology, the associahedra partition polynomials $A_n(u_1,...,u_n)$ are essentially the refined Euler characteristic polynomials of the convex associahedra polytopes, i.e., [associahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron). Unsigned, they are the refined face polynomials of the associahedra, flagging and enumerating the geometrically distinct faces of the associahedra. (See OEIS [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437), especially links therein to several of my MO-Q&As for more info.)

A 'sampling theorem' applies to these partition polynomials (ParPs) such that given a 'periodically sampled' infinite subset of monomials of the ParPs, the $A_n$ can be completely generated.

Explicitly, with the sampled subset

$$A_n^{(m)}(\hat{u}_1,...,\hat{u}_n) = A_{nm}(0,...,0,u_m,0,...,0,u_{2m},0,...,0,u_{3m},0,...,0,u_{nm})$$

where $\hat{u}_n = u_{nm}$, then the lowering operation, a combination of multiplicative and compositional inversion,

$$ \frac{x}{(xA^{(m)}(x))^{(-1)}} = A^{(m-1)}(x) $$

can be used iteratively to generate $A(x)$.

There is a raising operation as well;

$$\left (\frac{ x}{ A^{(m)}(x)} \right )^{(-1)} = xA^{(m+1)}(x).$$

Explicitly (now treating $u_k$ as dummy indeterminates),
$$
\begin{split}
A^{(m)}_n(u_1,...,u_n) & = \sum_\text{partitions of $n$} M^{(m)}(e_1,e_2,...,e_n) u_1^{e_1}u_2^{e_3}\ldots u_n^{e_n}\\
& = \sum_\text{partitions of $n$} (-1)^{Se} \frac{1}{mn+1} \frac{(mn+Se)!}{(mn)!e_1!e_2!\ldots e_n!}    u_1^{e_1}u_2^{e_3}\ldots u_n^{e_n}.
\end{split}
$$
A combinatorial reciprocity applies with $m$ being any integer and
$$
\begin{split}
M^{(m)}(e_1,e_2,...,e_n) & = (-1)^{Se} \frac{1}{mn+1} \frac{(mn+Se)!}{(mn)!e_1!e_2!\ldots e_n!} \\
& = \frac{1}{mn+1} \frac{(-mn-1!}{(-mn-1-Se)!e_1!e_2!\ldots e_n!}.
\end{split}
$$
The particular case with all the indeterminates for a fixed $m$ nulled, i.e., set to $0$, except for $u_1$ gives the coefficient of $A_n^{(m)}(u_1,0,0,...)$, the diagonal coefficient of $A_n^{(m)}(u_1,...,u_n)$, as the signed generalized Fuss-Catalan number sequences

$$FC^{(m)}_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{mn+1} \binom{(m+1)n}{n} = \frac{1}{mn+1} \binom{-mn-1}{n},$$

so then the $A^{(m)}(x)$ become $FC^{(m)}(x)$, the o.g.f.s for the signed (m)-Fuss-Catalan number / diagonal (m)-associahedra sequence.

Again, $m$ can be any integer, with $FC_n^{(-1)}(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0}FC_n^{(-1)}x^n = 1 - x$ and $m=1$ and $-2$ giving variants of the Catalan numbers (A000108).

Dual results apply to the noncrossing partitions / parking function partition polynomials of OEIS [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264) and their diagonals, the Fuss-Narayana sequences; the Lagrange inversion partition polynomials for e.g.f.s of [A134685](https://oeis.org/A134685); and the refined Eulerian partition polynomials of [A145271](https://oeis.org/A145271), all related to compositional and multiplicative inversion.

**Question: What other families of partition polynomials display similar sampling properties?**

Since the associahedra polynomial $xA(x)$ gives compositional inverses, the lowering operation seems something of a slight of hand veiling the appearance of the full polynomial, but the compositional inversion can be achieved several ways--with the classic Lagrange inversion formula, a fixed point equation, an iterated Lie derivative, a Laplace transform method, Sheffer binomial polynomial formalism and matrix inversion, and even geometrically with reflection through the line $y=x$ or the envelope method and the Legendre-Fenchel transform.,